# Eve Online can't switch to GeForce gt555

Tags: technical-issues, eve-online, graphics-card

I have laptop with two graphic cards: one is an Intel integrated chipset, and the other is a GeForce GT555M.

When I watch the settings window in Eve Online, I see that it uses the Intel chip, but I can't switch to GeForce because there is only the one option in the list.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? How can I switch to the GeForce?

**Edit:** I have Lenovo Y570 laptop. Integrated card is Intel HD Graphic 3000. And also I set GeForce card by default for all programs using "NVIDIA Control Panel".

Comment: can you post your laptop specs here?  Are you running one with a physical switch or is optimus enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a [known issue](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=38105) for Eve Online.

The good news is that even though its reporting just the Intel HD 3000, it should switch over to using the GT555m when optimus kicks in while in the game, so you don't have to worry about it.

[This link](http://www.trustedreviews.com/laptops/review/2010/02/24/nVidia-Optimus-Explained/p3) shows you how to set optimus for Eve Online manually in case it doesn't switch for you.

Comment: By the nature of Optimus graphics, some utilities will always report the Intel card being used instead.  If Optimus is properly configured, those utilities are almost always WRONG.  There is a very arcane technical reason for this that I won't bore the audience with here.

Comment: @Shinrai I would like to know. :)

Comment: @muntoo - The short version is that you're never actually using the Nvidia chip directly in Optimus mode.  When the system decides that it needs that power, the Nvidia chip does the rendering *and then inserts the image directly into the framebuffer of the Intel chip*.  So, depending on how you check for 'what adapter is in use', it may look like it's coming from the Intel when really the Nvidia is doing the work.  (This is oversimplified, so as to fit in a comment, but basically this is what's happening)